# Как при создании файла средствами python присвоить файлу свою иконку

Tags: c++, python

Я пишу программу для шифрования файлов на Python. У файла своё личное расширение(ни одно другое под мои задачи не подходит) и я чтобы файл не был без иконки, я нарисовал свою в формате *.ico. При создании файла через python...

```
#something like this
open('somefile.bc', 'w').close()
```

я хочу чтобы им присваивалась моя иконка (ну к примеру как visual studio создаёт файл своего проэкта со своим расширением и иконкой). Я хочу узнать возможно ли это в Python, а если нет, то может это возможно на c++? Буду очень благодарен ибо нигде не нашёл ответ.

Comment: Вам видимо потребуется зарегистрировать свое расширение в системе. [How to Assign a Custom Icon to a File Type](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/desktop/shell/how-to-assign-a-custom-icon-to-a-file-type)

Comment: Не понял, всмысле?, а если я хочу чтобы это было и на других компах которые ставят себе эту прогу

Comment: Ну там по ссылке описывается, как задать иконку файлам со своим расширением.

Comment: Я понял, спасибо